# SQL Server query to calculate daily “carrying” open orders

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have searched across the site, but can’t seem to find a solution that fits my particular issue. There are many that are close to what I"m looking for, but not enough (at least for my coding ability) to make the connection.

I have a relatively simple table which has:

- Order_Number
- Order_Date
- Fulfilled_Date

There are a number of other fields, but they are not pertinent to this issue.

I need to create a report that shows (on a daily breakdown) how many orders were “unfulfilled” across a 30-day period. Obviously, a “null” value indicates an order is currently unfulfilled, but I am really struggling with how to approach the question of how many unfulfilled orders are being carried across on a daily basis.

In some cases, an order could be placed months ago, and remain unfulfilled (potentially due to a back-order state), so I need to look back almost to the beginning of time for the table.

Also, for this problem, consider that I do not have a “date” or “day” table available and am unable to make one.  I can build one in a temp table, but nothing permanent. Additionally, I only have to worry about a 30 day period from “today” (getdate()-30)

Sample Data:

```
create table #orders 
(
    order_number varchar(25),
    order_date datetime,
    fulfilled_date datetime
)

insert into #orders (order_number, order_date, fulfilled_date)
values ('HK02411580-92880', '2/22/17 23:06', '2/27/17 23:11'),
       ('HK02411580-93259', '2/22/17 11:22', '2/22/17 16:27'),
       ('HK02411580-93760', '2/22/17 23:46', '2/22/17 23:51'),
       ('HK02411580-94122', '2/23/17 0:06', '2/25/17 0:16'),
       ('HK02411580-94845', '2/23/17 0:42', '2/26/17 0:42'),
       ('HK02411580-94847', '2/23/17 0:42', '2/23/17 0:42'),
       ('HK02411580-94952', '2/23/17 0:46', '2/23/17 0:51'),
       ('BS63719405-53119', '2/24/17 23:44', '2/25/17 23:44'),
       ('BS63719405-53231', '2/24/17 23:48', '2/28/17 23:49'),
       ('BS63719405-53336', '2/24/17 23:54', '2/24/17 23:54'),
       ('BS63719405-53546', '2/25/17 0:04', '2/27/17 0:04'),
       ('BS63719405-53672', '2/25/17 0:09', '2/28/17 0:09'),
       ('UT40057640-11866', '2/26/17 23:06', '3/1/17 23:11'),
       ('UT40057640-11910', '2/26/17 23:07', '3/5/17 23:17'),
       ('UT40057640-13217', '2/27/17 0:11', '2/27/17 0:16'),
       ('UT40057640-13829', '2/27/17 0:41', '2/27/17 0:41'),
       ('UT40057640-93881', '3/1/17 13:28', '3/1/17 13:29'),
       ('UT40057640-94117', '3/1/17 13:38', '3/5/17 13:39'),
       ('SC79933239-74181', '3/3/17 22:02', '3/4/17 22:08'),
       ('SC79933239-76349', '3/3/17 23:32', '3/3/17 23:37'),
       ('SC79933239-76716', '3/3/17 23:51', '3/3/17 23:56'),
       ('SC79933239-77351', '3/4/17 0:18', '3/5/17 0:19'),
       ('SC79933239-77899', '3/4/17 0:41', '3/6/17 0:41'),
       ('SC79933239-77900', '3/4/17 0:41', '3/4/17 0:41'),
       ('FM76423870-59430', '3/6/17 9:54', '3/10/17 9:54'),
       ('FM76423870-59552', '3/6/17 9:59', '3/11/17 9:59'),
       ('FM76423870-59676', '3/6/17 10:03', '3/9/17 10:04'),
       ('FM76423870-59798', '3/6/17 10:09', '3/6/17 10:09'),
       ('IE68709323-78813', '3/20/17 7:01', '3/20/17 7:53'),
       ('IE68709323-78905', '3/20/17 7:09', '3/20/17 7:53'),
       ('RC45792362-15830', '3/20/17 7:59',     NULL),
       ('RC45792362-15831', '3/20/17 7:59',     NULL),
       ('RC45792362-16653', '3/20/17 8:39',     NULL),
       ('RC45792362-24157', '3/20/17 14:52',    NULL),
       ('RC45792362-24163', '3/20/17 14:52', '3/20/17 14:57'),
       ('RC45792362-24223', '3/20/17 14:54',    NULL),
       ('RC45792362-24327', '3/20/17 14:56', '3/20/17 14:59'),
       ('RC45792362-24267', '3/20/17 14:57',    NULL),
       ('RC45792362-27486', '3/20/17 17:32',    NULL),
       ('RC45792362-27607', '3/20/17 17:36', '3/20/17 17:39');
```

Desired output would be (for example):

```
 Date          Carry Over Orders
 ---------     -----------------
 2/22/2017     1 (3 orders...2 fulfilled and one left over  or "carried over")
 2/23/2017     3 (2 orders fulfilled that day, but 2 additional carried over)
 2/24/2017     5 (1 order fulfilled that day, but 2 additional carried over)
 2/25/2017     5 (2 orders fulfilled from prior dates but 2 new orders carried over)

 Etc...
```

I hope I explained this right...seemed simple enough when I started out down this path, but it's just not clicking right in the brain...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Server version: SQL Server 2008

One more item to add:  for dates with no orders, I would still need to account for them...I am expecting to have to script some sort of temporary date table based on starting date and working backward 30 days...unless there is a better way.

Clarification:  in the result set, "Carry Over Orders" is essentially a running total of orders that were not fulfilled through that particular date.

Logic clarification:

On the 22nd there were 3 total orders...2 of them were fulfilled (or shipped if you prefer) and one was not.  This leaves 1 unfulfilled order going into the 23rd.

On the 23rd there were 4 total orders.  2 of them were fulfilled that day and 2 were not.  The order from the prior day(s) still are outstanding which brings the total "Carry over" to 3 orders.

On the 24th we have an additional 3 orders.  1 was fulfilled that day, and two was not.  Total carry over is now 5

On the 25th we have 2 new orders that were not fulfilled that day, but 2 prior orders were (one from the 23rd and one from the 24th).  Total number of Carr-over orders (or outstanding orders) remains at 5.

Hope this helps a bit more

To help in this, I have created a rextester (since sqlfiddle seems broken)
[rextester sandbox](http://rextester.com/FVGQL96587)

Comment: what does the 1, 3, 5, and 5 represent in the second column?

Comment: Sorry...those would be the total number of unfulfilled orders through that day.

Comment: why does 2/22/2017 not have fulfilled orders?

Comment: The need is for "un-fulfilled" orders. 2/22 (the start) had  2 orders fulfilled, but 1 order unfulfilled, so it would be considered a carry-over

Comment: you might want to clarify what you mean by Carry over orders.

Comment: i guess what i'm try to say is why does 2/22 also say 1 without (2 fulfilled that day)?

Comment: That was just me trying to clarify why that number would be 1.  Three total orders...2 were filled but one was unfulfilled and carried out (in that record it was finally fulfilled on the 27th...updated the needed output notes to reflect that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the desired output.  This query assumes you have a distinct listing of dates to query against.

The portion you had the most trouble with, the carry over, uses a `FROM` statement that references two datasets.  This is different from a `JOIN` and is done by referencing two tables and separating them with a `,`.  This will in turn create a query where each date in the `dates_table` gets assigned the entire dataset from the `orders` table.  In order to determine carry over a `WHERE` statement is used to filter the copied orders table and a `GROUP BY` is used count each filtered order.  After that a `LEFT JOIN` is used to pull the results by date to the `date_table`.  Feel free to leave a comment if you want more explanation.

**SQL with Dates Table** this table is named `dates_table` in the query below

```
SELECT 
    dates.date,
    iif(carry_over.count IS NULL, 0, carry_over.count) AS carry_over,
    iif(fulfilled.count IS NULL, 0, fulfilled.count) AS fulfilled,
    iif(not_fulfilled.count IS NULL, 0, not_fulfilled.count) AS not_fulfilled

FROM dates_table AS dates

/* Fulfilled that day */
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, fulfilled_date), 0) AS date, 
        COUNT(dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, fulfilled_date), 0)) AS count
    FROM orders
    GROUP BY dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, fulfilled_date), 0)
) AS fulfilled
    ON dates.date = fulfilled.date

/* Not Fulfilled that day */
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, order_date), 0) AS date, 
        COUNT(dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, order_date), 0)) AS count
    FROM orders
    WHERE (dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, order_date), 0) <> dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, fulfilled_date), 0)) OR fulfilled_date IS NULL
    GROUP BY dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, order_date), 0)
) AS not_fulfilled
    ON dates.date = not_fulfilled.date

/* Carry Over */
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        full_data.date,
        COUNT(full_data.order_date) AS count

    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            dates.date AS date,
            order_dates.order_date AS order_date,
            order_dates.fulfilled_date AS fulfilled_date

        FROM dates_table AS dates,

        /* Allocate all dates to key of dates, filter out what is relevant in where */
        (
            SELECT 
                dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, order_date), 0) AS order_date,
                iif(fulfilled_date IS NULL, NULL, dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, fulfilled_date), 0)) AS fulfilled_date
            FROM orders
        ) AS order_dates

    ) AS full_data

    /* Determines what is carry over */
    WHERE (full_data.date < full_data.fulfilled_date OR full_data.fulfilled_date IS NULL) AND full_data.date >= full_data.order_date
    GROUP BY full_data.date

) AS carry_over
    ON dates.date = carry_over.date
```

[rextester](http://rextester.com/IPEE83057)

Edit: Added field names for final query as they were all labeled count before

Edit: Added another query assuming you have a table of dates and # for orders table

Edit: Removed query without date_table, count on carry_over now done on order_date as was not counting nulls, for fulfilled that day numbers now pulls fulfilled_date instead of order_date

Comment: This definitely gives me the data..I will need to use a date table though, as I do need to show contiguous dates...so if there are no orders for a particular day, there would still be "pending' orders or "carry over" orders...do you have a suggestion on how to integrate that part?

Comment: I will post another sql query assuming you have a table of dates.

Comment: @Buckwheattb I have updated my answer.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I could also space mine like you did yours and it would take up a whole lot less

Comment: @DavidLee  This is close, but it seems to come apart when the query hits dates that have no activity (missing date ranges in the orders table)...I made a date table that ran from 2/20 through 3/21 as a test.  The answer set looked good in the early days, but once it hit the period of no orders (particularly the 3/6 through 3/20 period) the results were off...one other thing...in the "not fulfilled that day" portion, I made a change to accommodate "NULL" fulfilled dates..."isnull(dateadd(d, datediff(d,0, fulfilled_date), 0),'1/1/2050')"  Does that make sense?

Comment: @DavidLee -- I used your solution as the starting point on that rextester link.

Comment: @Buckwheattb please view updated answer, I also included an updated rextester.  Please let me know if this does not provide the desired result.

Comment: I think this is the answer....initial tests look perfect.  I will put it into my DB and let you know definitively in a little bit....but I think this is perfect!  Thank you SOOOOO much!

Comment: Quick update for you.  I have tested this and it gives me exactly what I was looking for.  Looking at the code, I knew this was a problem above my TSQL capabilities...thank you very much @DavidLee ... Greatly Appreciated!

Comment: @Buckwheattb Awesome, glad to be of service.  Good luck with your future developments!